# Setup function using datetime to loop over values of dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, model, range, gurobi

I am trying to set up a model in gurobi. I would like to iterate over the values in a dictionary, that looks like this:

```
2016-01-01 00:00:00+01:00    23.86
2016-01-01 01:00:00+01:00    22.39
2016-01-01 02:00:00+01:00    20.59
```

I have tried various set up with daterange, series, dataframes, values, keys etc. but cannot get this to work. The date and time are keys in format `datetime64[ns]` and the values are floats.

I want to set up a function in the gurobi model that loops over the values by means of the datetime index as you would normally do with, e.g. `for t in range(T)`, but I can't get it to work. I can't find an explicit solution to this online, or I am applying the solutions incorrectly. I would like the time to be coupled to the value as I want to import other data which does no have correspondent deltaT's.

Comment: It isn't clear what you are trying to do: you can iterate over key:value pairs easily using the dictionary's [`items()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.items) method.

Comment: I have tried that as follows (dap denotes the values starting with 23.86): for i in range(dap.items):
    y = dap(i)*5. which gives me the following error: TypeError: 'method' object cannot be interpreted as an integer. It must be a very simple mistake but 4 hours of debugging did not bring a solution yet

Comment: Did you look at the documentation I linked to?

Comment: i did, and have been able to execute a function on the values. Thanks so far, however i did it this way not using iter(): for val in dap.values:
    n = 5+val
    print (n). 
Is there anything I am missing or is this e.g. very inefficient?

Comment: I am looking to set up a formula similar to this one while using the dictionary: ((P_grid_b[t] * c[t]) for t in range(T)) Which does not correspond with the one I have currently. Would you have any suggestions